# "Received" mail header contains virtual domain

Tags: postfix

I configured Postfix for some virtual domains. When I inspect the headers of messages delivered via my server, one of these domains appears as part of the "Received" header":

```
Received: from actual.hostname.tld (virtual.domain.tld [1.2.3.4])
```

Why does virtual.domain.tld appear in this header? It is always the same domain, although Postfix' main.cf contains 9 `virtual_alias_domains`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a reverse DNS query

`virtual.domain.tld` is surely the PTR record for 1.2.3.4

Try:
`dig -x 1.2.3.4`